# How to split json field into multi-rows?

Tags: mariadb

I have a JSON field in a table in which the data might be stored as one or more elements (i.e. "[{a: 1, b:2}]" or "[{a: 1, b:2},{b: 1, c:2}]").

How can I generate MariaDB query to result in the following:

```
A          B          C
===========================
1          2          NULL
NULL       1          2
```

Of course the "NULL" value can be altered but the idea is that a JSON array will be shown as row for each element.

I know that MySQL have JSON_TABLE function with the new versions, i'm looking for MariaDB equivalent.

Comment: If you are trying to manipulate JSON in SQL, you possibly needed _not_ to store the info as JSON.

Comment: The problem is the data source i'm dealing with doesn't have fixed structure. It can be converted somehow but any future change will require bit amount of work.

Comment: Split out only the relatively "common" fields.  Presumably, those are the fields you need to manipulate with MySQL.  Meanwhile, leave the rest (or all) the fields in the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I noticed a lot of people use a table with predefined numbers (0 till who_knows). For example a table called numbers with one field (n) from 1 to 200 (depending on how many splits might happen).

The query that makes it work is as follows:

Assuming rawData is a JSON string that have "events" as the json array that you want to split into rows.

```
SELECT
    logEvent, JSON_EXTRACT(logEvent, "$.author_name"), JSON_EXTRACT(logEvent, "$.text")
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        JSON_EXTRACT(
            rawData,
            CONCAT('$.events[', num.n, ']')
        ) AS logEvent
    FROM
        numbers num
    INNER JOIN logsRaw 
) AS a
```